# Program is not accessing correct index of array.. Why?

Tags: c++, indexing

I come to this site in need of help, after struggling with this problem for a few days now. I am trying to program a poem that accepts some data from standard input and then outputs a poem based on that data.

The code seems to be working, but it is not correct! It is giving me the wrong index of the array I am using. I would love extra eyes to help me with my code and let me know what I am doing wrong.

ALSO! For some reason, I am not able to access the third array of the char array... I tried to place "SIZE - 1" in there but it prints nothing... Would love to understand why this is. Does this look right?

```
 // Program that accepts some data from standard input, 


#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//here... extracted. 
    for (int sign = 0; sign < poem[line]; sign++)
    {
      if (line > word_count)
      {
        std::cout << " ";
        print_poem(seed);
      }
      else
      {
        print_poem(seed);
      }
```

Comment: Always start by [enabling your compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/7GEPe1o84).  `int poem[num_lines];` is creating a variable length array (which is not valid C++) from an uninitialized `num_lines` (which causes Undefined Behavior)

Comment: Thanks, Drew! I will check that out right now.. not sure why it is doing that now

Comment: Maybe `if (other > word_count)` must be replaced with `if (other >= word_count)`? `if (other > word_count)` is especially suspicious when 1 is added to `word_count`.

Comment: Nit: If you're gonna define constants, use them. `HIRAGANA[9][5][4]` Why not use your constants here?

Comment: The problem is, when I try to use the third index and place SIZE in it - it does not print. I don't know why it does that.. why it works with 2 indexes but not three like its original. @Taekahn.. even if put in SIZE - 1.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! However, the problem still persists :/

Comment: Learn to write code in small functions. If you would be easy to turn your code into a test if function `main` had been small.

Comment: I surely will try to start doing that now @MarekR! My apolygies.

Comment: For the record, i thought all the code in main was code you couldn't change. But now that i see i was mistaken, if "poem" is holding the number of lines you want to output, why are you doing this ` word_count = seed % poem[other] + 1;` instead of `word_count = poem[other] ` Also, did you noticed what @drew said about uninitialized data? Probably a factor here.  Also, i think your code would be a lot easier to read if you picked better names. For instance, why `other` instead of `line` `line < num_lines` gives a lot more contextual meaning than `other < num_lines`.

Comment: Thank you, @Taekahn. I will make the necessary adjustments now; however, I put seed % poem[other] + 1; because I thought that would help determine how many syllables would be in the line.

Comment: `letters` value is unused.

Comment: Yes, I know. That variable is going to be used to indicate whether the poem is capitalized or not @MarekR :)

Comment: Problem is that your question do not contain any rationale explaining how output should be achieved. We see you have predefined random number generator, but there is no description how use this generator to achieve desired result. Please paste whole description of your task. I see that in comments other obvious bugs has been fixed. Anything else require full description of task.

Comment: Ok. @TedLyngmo... I am still new here, please allow me time to understand how this site works. Thank you. The answer that helped me has been accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what exactly the task is but I can at least explain to you parts of the problem.

### Are the correct syllables being printed?

Let's assess if the correct syllables are being printed. I ran your code on my machine (with the input you provided that is "100 3 1 5 7 5") and got:

```
nahoewachi
tetsunnunoyasa
munahohuke
```

The syllable count of each line is fine (5,7,5) so that's not a problem.
The first syllable you have a problem with is **chi** in nahoewa**chi**. I'm only illustrating why this syllable is being printed. You can apply the same logic to the rest.

Initially, the seed is 100. Before processing the first row, you apply generate_prnd, which gives 223. Before calculating **chi**, you print 4 other syllables (na, ho, e and wa). This means that you have applied generate_prnd 8 times before calculating the fifth syllable.

Applying generate_prnd 8 times on 223 gives 711. Applying one more time (to get row) gives 822.

822%9 = **3rd row** (0 indexed).

Applying one more time (to get column) gives 361. 361%5 = **1st column**.

Therefore the index for the fifth syllable is **(3,1)**. The string at the (3,1)th index is "chi". **Therefore, the correct syllable is being printed. The indexing is correct.** There's a problem with your logic if you want a different syllable to be printed.

### Now, let's assess why there aren't any spaces in your output.

In the example you provided, num_lines=3. The word_counts (actually syllable counts) are 5, 7 and 5. You are applying a space when line (which is always less than num_lines) is greater than word_count.

However, line is always less than word_count since the maximum value of line is 2 (num_lines - 1). Therefore, a space will never be printed.

P.S. If you are allocating memory using *new*, don't forget to deallocate using **delete** later.

Comment: This was an amazing review/explanation of my code @Harsh Motwani! But, I must say that my confusion was that instead of the poem getting "chi" it was supposed to get "ka." The 1st element of the second row, And it is supposed to print a space AFTER completing the first word before going to the next, rather than for each variable.Any suggestions?

Comment: I can tell you how you can implement the space part. However, there's no way I can no how to get (1,0) instead of (3,1). The math is too complex. You're regenerating the seed nine times before we get there. Plus, I don't know any of the context.
Onto the space part: Keep a count of the number of syllables printed. When it reaches the requirement of the word, print a space and reset the counter (set count=0).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion!